# Enum inside other enum

Tags: enums

```
Public enum BASECOLORS {
   GREEN,
   RED
}

public enum ALLCOLORS {
   VOILET,
   ORANGE
}
```

in the above code how can I access ALLCOLORS.GREEN? ALLCOLORS should have direct access to the BASECOLORS..

Please help me with your suggestions...

Comment: What language are you writing this in?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. Enums are primitives and cannot inherit from other enums, as inheritance is a property of objects.